# Problema con un IF

Tags: java

Estoy aprendiendo a programar en Java, y tengo un problema,
Tengo que ingresar 8 salario a un par de arreglos, uno de la mañana y otro de la tarde, y lo ideal seria que cuando ya s ellene un arreglo, lo pase para el otro arreglo, Podria compartirles el codigo para que me ayuden con eso ?

```
package prueba;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Prueba {
    private Scanner teclado;
    private int[] Mañana,Tarde;
    private int Total;
    private int MT;
    private int HM, HT;

    public void cargar()
    {
        System.out.println("Solo se pueden registrar 8 empleados.");
        HM = 0;
        HT = 0;
        Mañana = new int[4];
        Tarde = new int[4];
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Turno Mañana: 1 - Turno Tarde: 2 ");
            MT = teclado.nextInt();
            if (MT == 1) {
                if (HM >= 4) {
                    System.out.println("No puede ingresar mas salarios en la mañana.");
                    teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
                    System.out.println("Ingresar salario Tarde: ");
                    Tarde[i]=teclado.nextInt();
                    HT++;    
                }
                else {
                    teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
                    System.out.println("Ingresar salario Mañana: ");
                    Mañana[i]=teclado.nextInt();
                    HM++;
                }
            }else if (MT == 2) {
                if (HT > 4) {
                    System.out.println("No puede ingresar mas salarios en la tarde.");
                    teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
                    System.out.println("Ingresar salario Mañana: ");
                    Mañana[i]=teclado.nextInt();
                    HM++;
                    }
                else{
                    teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
                    System.out.println("Ingresar salario Tarde: ");
                    Tarde[i]=teclado.nextInt();
                    HT++;    


     }
        }else{
            System.out.println("nada");
        }     
    }
}

public static void main(String[] ar) {
        Prueba pv=new Prueba();
        pv.cargar();
       // pv.promedio();
        //pv.conteo();

    }
```

Entra al punto cuando identifica que ya el arreglo esta lleno, me pide el valor para llenar el otro arreglo, pero no se sale de los ciclos if y no vuelve al ciclo for. Es un programa tonto, pero no se como avanzar, gracias por leer.

Comment: No crees un `Scanner` cada vez que haya que leer un valor, reúsa el mismo.

Comment: Voy a probar...

Comment: Me sigue dando el mismo error:

Turno Mañana: 1 - Turno Tarde: 2 
1
No puede ingresar mas salarios en la mañana.
Ingresar salario Tarde: 
600
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4

Comment: No, no digo que esté relacionado con tu error. Pero es una cosita a mejorar.

Comment: ahhh, Jajaja, Pero si claro, ahorro mucho codigo. Gracias :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es tu índice, ya que cuando `i == 4`, está saliendo del límite del arreglo, cambia todas tus variables de índice por los int que están aumentando,es decir HM para la mañana y HT para la tarde.

quedaría así

```
public class Prueba {
private Scanner teclado;
private int[] Mañana,Tarde;
private int Total;
private int MT;
private int HM, HT;

public void cargar()
{
    System.out.println("Solo se pueden registrar 8 empleados.");
    HM = 0;
    HT = 0;
    Mañana = new int[4];
    Tarde = new int[4];
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Turno Mañana: 1 - Turno Tarde: 2 ");
        MT = teclado.nextInt();
        if (MT == 1) {
            if (HM >= 4) {
                System.out.println("No puede ingresar mas salarios en la mañana.");
                teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("Ingresar salario Tarde: ");
                Tarde[HT]=teclado.nextInt();
                HT++;    
            }
            else {
                teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("Ingresar salario Mañana: ");
                Mañana[HM]=teclado.nextInt();
                HM++;
            }
        }else if (MT == 2) {
            if (HT > 4) {
                System.out.println("No puede ingresar mas salarios en la tarde.");
                teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("Ingresar salario Mañana: ");
                Mañana[HM]=teclado.nextInt();
                HM++;
                }
            else{
                teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("Ingresar salario Tarde: ");
                Tarde[HT]=teclado.nextInt();
                HT++;    


 }
    }else{
        System.out.println("nada");
    }     
}
}

public static void main(String[] ar) {
        Prueba pv=new Prueba();
        pv.cargar();
       // pv.promedio();
        //pv.conteo();

    }
```

Un consejo muy importante, nunca uses "ñ" para nombre de variables, ya que puede causar errores

Comment: Efectivamente, tienes razón, y de la manera que me lo explicas funciona, peor lo que no entiendo es porque no funciona con el Tarde[i]=teclado.nextInt();, Si se supone que el i es estatico y al no haber vuelvo al ciclo for no cambia. Tu me podrias explicar ?

Comment: por qué dices que el i es estático? el i va aumentando en cada for, no entiendo en dónde está tu duda

Comment: Mi duda es puntualmente, porque no funciona con el i, si corresponde al mismo valor del HM, o del HT.

Comment: No corresponde, si te das cuenta HM cuando dices que es >= 4 entonces el que sumas es HT, es decir ahorta HM vale 4 y HT 1, sin embargo i siempre suma +1 en cada iteración, por lo que cuando HM vale 4 y HT 1, entonces "i" vale 5 y esá fuera del rango

Comment: Claro, tiene todo el sentido de la vida jajaja, Gracias por la explicación.